# Firebase User Sign Out

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm setting up authenticate with Firebase.I am login successfully but when ı log out my app crash

I create menu on activity_menu.Menu item name is log_out.If user click this item,user must log off

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case  R.id.logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I tried this code to see error but it didn't show me

```
 switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.logout: {

            try {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Log.e("LOG", "ERROR: " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I expected it is run successfully,I don't see any error.How can I figure out?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: app is stopped.

Comment: what does it say in LogCat?

Comment: "app is stopped" isn't an error given by java

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I updated my question,I couldn't figure out.@AlexMamo

Comment: If the app crashes, like there's a popup saying "appName has stopped responding" or "appName has crashed", there's definitely going to be a error in the LogCat. Are you using Android Studio?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()){

    case  R.id.logout:
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        return true;
}

return false;
}

Try this
```

Comment: After I clicked log_out,I must see loginActivity.